# База данных компании, правильно ли?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Хочу спросить правильно ли я реализовал? и как реализовать последние три пункта можете подсказать? или дать совет

> There is a Сompany and Employees of this Company
>
> The Company could be located in one or several cities, in one or
>   several buildings. The company can occupy the whole building or just a
>   part of a building.
>
> Employees have some Positions in a Company
>
> Employees have a Contract
>
> An Employee can be Promoted periodically
>
> An Employee passes Assessment procedure once a year. As a result of
>   Assessment, he/she could be either promoted or not.
>
> At each Company’s location there must be at least one Employee with
>   “Fire-protection safety” role.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]